# How to define a variable describing several options?

Tags: variable-definitions

```
Plot[y=x, {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 24, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

I will make several plots using the same sentences `PlotPoints -> 24, MaxRecursion -> 0, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0`. How can I define `variable= PlotPoints -> 24, MaxRecursion -> 0, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0` to simplfy the code like this:

```
Plot[y=x, {x, -1, 1}, variable]
```

Comment: Try:`variable = {PlotPoints -> 24, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0}; Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Evaluate@variable]`?

Comment: To splice in a list of options, try `Sequence@@list`.